# How to use react-router's new Multi-app feature with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I read the documentation for react-routerV6 and was going to try the Multi-app feature but in their example, they are using vite and I have create-react-app apps that I want to connect each other with

is there a way to use the feature with create-react-app?